# Trigger a Raphael mouseover event bound to a path using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, jquery-events

I have a map of the US states and counties drawn using Raphael.  In addition, each path has a `mouseover` and `mouseout` event bound to it.  Each path as a FIPS ID number as the element ID

I also have a jQuery autocomplete text input box.  Upon `keyup` and `keydown` events in the suggestion dropdown list, I'd like to trigger the associated path ID `mouseover` event handler.

Given a map drawn by:

```
function drawMap(data) {
  map = Raphael(document.getElementById("us_map_container", 555, 352));
  var pathCount = data.length;

  for (i = 0; i < pathCount; i++) {
    var currentPath = map.path(data[i][2]),
    pid = data[i][1],
    pname = data[i][0];

    currentPath.node.setAttribute("id", pid);
    currentPath.node.setAttribute("name", pname);
    currentPath.attr({"stroke" : "#FFFFFF", "fill" : "#CBCBCB", "stroke-width" : "0.2"});

    currentPath.mouseover(function(e){countyMouseOver(e)});
    currentPath.mouseout(function(e){countyMouseOut(e)});
  }
}
```

and the associated `mouseover` event:

```
function countyMouseOver(e) {
    var hover = e.target;
    var name = hover.getAttribute("name");
    if (name != "#State_borders") {
        $(hover).attr({"stroke" : "#FF0000", "stroke-width" : "1", "fill" : "#FF0000"});
        console.log("Name: " + name + "  ID: " + hover.id);
    }
}
```

how can I execute a trigger event using this `keypress` listener?

```
$("#county_search_autocomplete").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13){
        var index = $.inArray($(this).val(), counties)
        if (index > 0){
            console.log("FIPS: " + counties[i].id);
        }
    }

    else if (e.which == 38 || e.which == 40){
         //trigger Raphael mouseover event... how?
    }
});
```